# How to use the extension Autoprefixer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoprefixer

I installed the AutoPrefixer plugin, trying to run it but it doesn't work.

I'm highlighting all of my CSS, then hit command pallet, then hit AutoPrefixer:run.

Nothing happens. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below section in `settings.json` for Autoprefixer -

```
"autoprefixer.options": {
    "browsers": [
        "last 4 versions",
        "ie >= 9",
        "> 5%"
    ]
}
```

and hit `AutoPrefixer:run` as you do before and it will work.